# Network program works in Linux, not under Cygwin

Tags: c, networking, cygwin

I've written a simple program that reads input from `stdin` and sends it over TCP to a server listening on port 15557.

When I compile and run it under Linux it works fine. However, when I try to compile and run it under Cygwin, it fails with the following error message:

```
$ ./a.out servername.net 15557 < test.dat
Unable to connect: Cannot assign requested address
```

I've ruled out any firewall/networking issues, as I am capable of connecting via telnet to that same server and send the same data entered by hand.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

**UPDATE**

Following @Hasturkun's clue, I've started the program under GDB to check what the result to `gethostbyname` is. Here it is, immediately after the `gethostbyname` call:

```
(gdb) print *serverent
$2 = {h_name = 0x603217 "bilbo.neurobat.net", h_aliases = 0x603030, h_addrtype = 2, h_length = 4, h_addr_list = 0x6031c0}
(gdb) print serverent->h_addr_list[0]
$3 = 0x60322c ">\002V0"
(gdb) print atoi(">\002V0")
$5 = 0
```

I do not understand how to interpret the ">\002V0" string. Is this supposed to be an internet address?

**/UPDATE**

FWIW, the whole program is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "neurocli.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char *line = NULL;
  char buf[40] = {0};
  ssize_t write_len = 0, read_len;
  size_t n = 0;
  int neuro_socket;

  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s host port\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }

  neuro_socket = open_tcp_socket(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));

  /* Main loop: connect, write, read, re-connect and finally close */
  while ((write_len=getline(&line, &n, stdin)) != -1) {
    printf("# %s", line);
    if (write(neuro_socket, line, write_len) < 0) {
      perror("Unable to write to server");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (*line=='\n') {
      read_len = read(neuro_socket, buf, 40);
      buf[read_len] = '\0';
      printf("%s", buf);
      close(neuro_socket);
      neuro_socket = open_tcp_socket(argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));
    }
    free(line);
    line = NULL; /* getline() needs this */
  }
  free(line);
  close(neuro_socket);
  return 0;
}


int open_tcp_socket(char *server, int port) {
  int result;
  static struct sockaddr_in *sockaddr;

  /* Create socket */
  if ((result = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("Unable to create socket");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (sockaddr==NULL)
    sockaddr = make_sockaddr(server, port); /* never mind the memory leak */

  /* Connect */
  if (connect(result, (struct sockaddr*)sockaddr, sizeof(*sockaddr)) != 0) {
    perror("Unable to connect");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  return result;
}

struct sockaddr_in *make_sockaddr(char *name, int port) {
  struct sockaddr_in *sockaddr = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  struct hostent *serverent;

  memset(sockaddr, 0, sizeof(*sockaddr));
  sockaddr->sin_family = AF_INET;
  sockaddr->sin_port = htons(port);

  if ((serverent = gethostbyname(name)) == NULL) {
    perror("Unable to lookup server IP address");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  sockaddr->sin_addr.s_addr = atoi(serverent->h_addr_list[0]);

  return sockaddr;
}
```

Comment: Is that your own error-message being printed out, or something from a library?  If it's your own (i.e., your own call to `perror` or something of that nature), then do you have the code-section for that?

Comment: @Jason I believe it comes from the failure to connect call to `perror`, about 6 lines from the end of the program.

Comment: wouldn't that say "Unable to lookup server IP address"? ... I just don't see anywhere it says "Unable to build data connection".  I'm assuming that part of the message is a string you've passed to `perror` somewhere.  If it's not, then I should be seeing one of your strings signifying a failed call to `connect`, etc.

Comment: @Jason I'm sorry, you're right. I was copying from memory a line seen on the client's machine. I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
sockaddr->sin_addr.s_addr = atoi(serverent->h_addr_list[0]);
```

Is incorrect. `h_addr_list` contains addresses of either `struct in_addr` or `struct in6_addr`, the length is given in `h_length` and the type can be determined via `h_addrtype`.

To get the address, `memcpy` or assign it to the appropriate type

Comment: I've started the program under GDB to check what happens on that line and updated the question with the results. I must say that I am even more confused now, because the program won't work under Linux anymore :-o

Comment: @lindelof: It isn't a string, it's a `struct in_addr` (which was previously wrong in my answer, since corrected) you can assign it eg. `sockaddr->sin_addr = *(struct in_addr*)serverent->h_addr_list[0];`

Comment: I'm flabbergasted, it works. But the `gethostyname(3)` page says that `gethostbyname` returns a struct whose `h_addr_list` field is a `char**`. How can `h_addr_list[0]` then be castable to `struct in_addr*`?

Answer (score 0):

The connect() call is failing because the address in invalid. Most likely the call to gethostbyname() is returning a structure with no useful addresses in it (i.e. h_addr_list[0] == 0).

Not really sure how cygwin interacts with the DNS client...

Comment: That could be. Actually, the program fails also under Linux, albeit in an unpredictable manner. See the update to the question.